# nmap deploy on AWS Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, nmap

Is it possible to deploy nmap on AWS server. If yes, please guide me how I will do that. Nmap will run for a port scanning on our internet facing servers.

Please let me know if any other details is required.

Answer (score 2):

You can do network scans from AWS services, but you need to fill out a request form; otherwise, you will breach their acceptable use policy. You can find more information about the actual request process [here](https://aws.amazon.com/security/penetration-testing/)

Comment: Dear Kush, So you mean it is possible to deploy nmap on AWS host. I understand I need their permission to scan any network. Could you please provide me link/document of how to deploy nmap on AWS host. Thanks in Advance

Comment: I would suggest you fill the form for that first and wait for aws confirmation